# Amazon Redshift node parallel requests take longer than sequential

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run a bunch of select queries on redshift from my node app using node-redshift and [pg](https://node-postgres.com/). If I run my queries in sequence, I get an average of 2 seconds per query. But when I run my queries in parallel, they take much longer, about 32 seconds for the last one.

I can clearly see that the clog is caused by parallel loading of queries. What can be done about it?

I can also conclude that Redshift doesn't take that long. Because the cached Redshift queries still take a considerable overhead.

**Sequential:**

[image: Sequential]

**Parallel:**

[image: Parallel]

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Redshift Workload Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_workload_mngmt_classification.html) can be used to configure concurrency, queues and memory allocation.

> By default, Amazon Redshift configures one queue with a *concurrency level* of five, which enables up to five queries to run concurrently, plus one predefined Superuser queue, with a concurrency level of one. You can define up to eight queues. Each queue can be configured with a maximum concurrency level of 50. The maximum total concurrency level for all user-defined queues (not including the Superuser queue) is 50.

Concurrent queries require permanently-allocated memory. This is fine if you are always running concurrent queries, but is wasteful if it only runs a small amount of the time.

A common practice is to create separate queues:

- One queue for long-running queries with low concurrency. This allocates lots of memory to each query but queries might be queued-up.
- One queue for short-running queries. This allows shorter queries to complete quickly without being impacted by long-running queries -- for example, to calculate dashboard queries every few minutes. Less memory is probably required for these types of queries, so concurrency can be increased.

**Bottom line:** By default, Redshift is configured for large, complex queries with low concurrency. You can adjust the settings.

Comment: We tried increasing the queue count and concurrency. But it showed exactly 0 effect. No idea why. The bottleneck seems to be somewhere else.